# Opposite of wailing to describe how a cello sounds

Tags: antonyms, sounds

I'm looking for a word to nicely describe how a cello sounds, and I think that an opposite of *wailing* might be a good description.

The [definition](https://www.lexico.com/definition/wail) for *wail* describes a high-pitched tone:

> **Wail**
>
> **1** A prolonged high-pitched cry of pain, grief, or anger.

So what would be the word for the same description, except it's a bass (or just low-pitched) tone?

The purpose is preparing subtitles for a [music video](https://youtu.be/hdYV8Xw87hs) which has cello playing, so it would be something like:

```
[Cello playing]
```

(But I want to replace "playing" with the cello sound word, in verb form)

Comment: i’m not sure how many of the descriptors you mean to invert. For instance, I’m pretty sure you still intend “prolonged.” So are you looking for a low-pitched cry of pain, grief, or anger, or for more pleasant connotations?

Comment: Prolonged - yes, pleasant - not necessarily.

Comment: I hear a cello as a melancholy groan.

Comment: I don't think cellos etc. can be characterized by one sound. Stringed instruments sound like stringed instruments and not like ones in which one blows or on which one drums.

Comment: I would use "mellow tones" in the first instance, and "mellowness" thereafter.

Comment: Patrick O'Brian sometimes refers to a cello 'booming'.

Comment: @AndyBonner - when I was 12, my secondary school was misguided enough to offer me free music lessons (my choice of instrument from a limited range) and I chose the cello. Old fashioned people still wrote 'cello because it's short for _violoncello_. Laboriously over a term I learned to hold the bow properly and play 'Baa Baa Black Sheep'. One weekend I took the school cello home on the bus. I set it up and began playing. Our family cat became very distressed and rather vocal. My father, grinning, said 'She can hear her mother'. I gave up soon after. I am not musically gifted.

Comment: Verb or adjective? Please give a sentence with a blank in it so we know the context you want. Then we can vote to reopen.

Comment: @Mitch, sure, added.

Comment: @HeyJude thanks for the edit, voted to reopen. By the way did. you happen to look up synonyms of 'wail'? That might start you on the way to finding  what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A low-pitch corollary to *wail* is **moan**: prolonged, primarily associated with grief or pain but can also have a counter-intuitive positive connotation ("a moan of pleasure").

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you choose a verb other than *playing*, it should also reflect *how* and *what* the cello is playing. I would describe the cello in the clip more as **droning** or **humming** than low-pitched wailing. These verbs are also more neutral in connotation and perhaps a better fit for the mood being created.

**drone** (v.)

> To emit a **continuous** steady deep **humming** or buzzing sound, esp. a
> continuous musical note of **low pitch**; to hum or buzz, like a bee or a
> bagpipe. OED

---

> The wind in the leaves hums like the violins singing; the clouds scud
> across a quarter moon like the **mellow drone** of the cello.  [Elaine
> Alphin; *Simon Says*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Simon_Says/T3lbZwpRZVcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22drone%20of%20the%20cello%22&pg=PT101&printsec=frontcover)

> While the simple duple meter is maintained in the **drone** of the cello ,
> the Indian theme uses a combination of three quarter notes , or a half
> note and quarter note per ... [Bernadette Kopp; *The Twelve-tone
> Techniques of Adolph Weiss*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Twelve_tone_Techniques_of_Adolph_Wei/mBU6AQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22drone%20of%20the%20cello%22&dq=%22drone%20of%20the%20cello%22&printsec=frontcover)

> The instrumentalists took their places, checked their scores, and
> emitted a **drone** of notes, moving first from the low-end registers
> of cello and bass to the violins and then to the winds, like a game of
> sonic tag, until all the instruments were on the same wavelength.
> [Eric Siblin; *The Cello Suites*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Cello_Suites/Euf2Loch7YcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cello%20drone%20bach&pg=PA49&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: droning is not considered a pleasant sound.

Comment: Not especially on the bagpipes, but the Bach Cello Suites have a fair amount and most folks find them pleasant enough. Drones are a  characteristic of musettes. Note "*mellow* drone" in the example.

Comment: bagpipes are not a stringed instrument.  humming and droning are not words I put use in movie descriptor: cello droning.....ugh.

Comment: If you find a drone on the cello unpleasant, fine, but others may disagree.